# how to use word cloud for twitter application

Tags: asp.net, jquery, ajax, twitter

I am working on a twitter application where i want to show all trend in word cloud.
but i don't know how to use word cloud and which api i will use for twitter to do this.

I want like this[Example](http://www.twitscoop.com/).

Please help me for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically to generate a tag cloud you need a list of words and their frequency. Twitter API does not provide you frequency of a term(word) as API result. So, you will have to get current trends from twitter API, store them locally and calculate the frequency of each term.

Simple and easy way to do this would be to query the [trends/daily](http://apiwiki.twitter.com/Twitter-Search-API-Method%3A-trends-daily) API which returns trending topics (by each hour) for a given day. Accumulate the terms from API result and count their frequency. I guess drawing the cloud using this list of words & frequency would be an easy task.

I hope this answers the question. But if you want something complex, you will have to monitor & process tweets using search,streaming API.

Comment: Thanks for reply But i need little more help.
First that Do you have any other way to solve this problem.
Suppose that if i will follow what you have told then 
if i will search any word then how can i calculate frequency of that word

Answer (score 0):

Using the twitter api you can get current trends, ie: http://apiwiki.twitter.com/Twitter-Search-API-Method%3A-trends-current

You'll probably want to have a look at the documentation at http://apiwiki.twitter.com/Twitter-API-Documentation

Comment: Thanks for your ans but problem is not solved here please tell me how can i show current trends in word cloud